# How to expand the ComboBox in a (WPF) DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

In my C# WPF application (.NET 4.0) I have a DataGrid dynamically filled from code including a DataGridComboBoxColumn:

```
public static DataGridComboBoxColumn getCboCol(string colName, Binding textBinding)
{
    List<string> statusItemsList = new StatusList();

    DataGridComboBoxColumn cboColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    cboColumn.Header = colName;
    cboColumn.SelectedItemBinding = textBinding;
    cboColumn.ItemsSource = statusItemsList;

    return cboColumn;
}
```

Using the BeginningEdit event different checks are performed.

If the checks return okay, I want to expand the combobox directly, otherwise edit mode is cancelled:

```
void dataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if(notOK)
        e.Cancel;
    else {
        DataGridComboBoxColumn dgCboCol = (DataGridComboBoxColumn)e.Column;
        // expand dgCboCol
    }
    ...
}
```

---

**Questions:** How to expand the combobox programmatically? Is BeginningEdit event the right place to do that?

---

**Answer:**

```
void dataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditingElement.GetType().Equals(typeof(ComboBox)))
    {
        ComboBox box = (ComboBox)e.EditingElement;
        box.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you do this dynamically instead of defining in the xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs`, you could access the generated element for the cell about to be edited like this:

```
var contentComboBox = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row) as ComboBox;
```

However, I'm not sure that this will get the actual ComboBox you need. DataGrids can generate two different elements for each cell, depending on whether they are in edit mode (read-only and read-write elements). Since `BeginningEdit` happens just before entering edit mode, this will get the read-only element.

The better event to handle this in would probably be [PreparingCellForEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.preparingcellforedit.aspx), which will fire after `BeginEdit` is actually called on the data item (in other words, if `BeginningEdit` was not canceled). In that event, you can access the element directly through the [EditingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.controls.datagridpreparingcellforediteventargs.editingelement.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08ef35de-5b22-4d3a-b815-f1fc535d8665/datagridcomboboxcolumn-auto-drop-down-on-single-click)

Try setting edit mode on the grid to a single click and then use the CellClick event to obtain the comboBox and expand it.

```
dataGrid.BeginEdit(true); 
ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)dataGrid.EditingControl; 
comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

Comment: There's no property called `EditingControl` on a `DataGrid`.