# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn does not display text if it is not in ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

In my C# WPF application I programmatically add a ComboBoxColumn to a DataGrid:

```
public static DataGridComboBoxColumn getCboCol(string colName, Binding textBinding)
{
    List<string> statusItemsList = new StatusStrList();

    DataGridComboBoxColumn cboColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    cboColumn.Header = colName;
    cboColumn.SelectedItemBinding = textBinding;
    cboColumn.ItemsSource = statusItemsList;

    return cboColumn;
}
```

If an item in the containing DataGrid contains text, which my `StatusStrList` doesn't contain, it won't be displayed.

**Example:** If my `StatusStrList` contains `A, B, C` and a DataGrid's item has `X`, the `X` won't be displayed as text in the ComboBox.

**How can I fix this?**

Thanks in advance,
Christian

Comment: Is there a particular reason this approach is used instead of pure XAML?

Comment: @Jim Neither columns nor items properties to bind are known at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridComboBoxColumn` isn't dynamic enough to do something like this but you can use `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Code below should achieve the functionality you need. It works by using a `CellTemplate` containing a `TextBlock` which easily displays an item that wouldn't be in the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox`. Going into edit mode will bring up the `ComboBox` that contains all of the items of the list.

```
        DataGridTemplateColumn cboColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        cboColumn.Header = colName;

        //DataTemplate for CellTemplate
        DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory txtBlkFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        txtBlkFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, textBinding);
        cellTemplate.VisualTree = txtBlkFactory;
        cboColumn.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

        //DataTemplate for CellEditingTemplate
        DataTemplate editTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory cboFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
        cboFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.TextProperty, textBinding);
        cboFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, statusItemsList);
        cboFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.IsEditableProperty, true);

        MouseEventHandler handler = new MouseEventHandler(delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
        {
            ComboBox cboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            cboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        });

        cboFactory.AddHandler(ComboBox.MouseEnterEvent, handler);

        editTemplate.VisualTree = cboFactory;
        cboColumn.CellEditingTemplate = editTemplate;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out soon. Does your code fit to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252269/how-to-expand-the-combobox-in-a-wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn)?

Comment: @Christian I updated it to fit the requirements of your other question. I'm not sure exactly _how_ you want it to trigger but I think it's pretty clear how to change it. You can also remove the code from your previous question, it's all handled here.